# C# vs Java thread-safety

Tags: c#, xamarin, thread-safety

In Java we can do something like

```
final string str = "I am a string";

Thread thread = new Thread(...{
    string str2 = "bla bla bla " + str;
});
```

I don't fully understand how to do it, but the point being I need to declare str as final to acces it in my thread so there is no varaible corruption.

But now how does I am supose to do it in C#

```
string str = "I am a string";

Task.Run(() => {
    string str2 = "bla bla " + str;
});
```

It does work, but I am not sure it's the right way to do it. I am using Visual Studio for Xamarin.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Why wouldn't your method be thread-safe?

Answer (score 9):

Let's take a step back.

When you create a lambda in C#, you capture outer variables *as variables*:

```
int x = 123;
Action change = () => { Console.WriteLine(x); x = 345; };
Console.WriteLine(x); // 123
change(); // 123
Console.WriteLine(x); // 345
change(); // 345
x = 789;
change(); // 789
Console.WriteLine(x); // 345
```

There is only *one variable x*, and it is *shared* by the lambda and the activation of the method.

This is very useful but there are situations where it can get *super confusing*:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{
  actions.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine(x); });
}
actions[0](); // 10, surprise!
```

There is only one variable x, and all the lambdas share it.

Some people want the first behaviour -- lambdas share variables -- but people who write the second kind of program want the second kind of behaviour.  They want lambdas to capture *the current value of a variable*, not *the variable itself*.

C# solves this problem by simply choosing the first option.  Java solves the problem by *making the first scenario illegal*.  If you can only capture *variables that never change* then you don't have either the benefits or the problems of capturing variables as variables.

I personally prefer the C# choice, despite its shortcomings. But both are reasonable, justifiable and principled. Different language designers make different choices.

The feature has nothing to do with thread safety per se. (Though there are thread safety aspects to it; variables shared across threads via lambdas in C# are *not volatile*.) Rather, it's a design decision about how lambda capture of variables works.

Comment: @eric given that both approaches are reasonable and that probably there are enough programmers hoping for the _by value_ approach...was it that difficult, for the compiler, to support both with a syntax like `ref i` (default by value and by ref on demand)?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Several languages have taken this approach. C++ lambdas allow you to specify whether variables are captured by value or reference. Anonymous functions in Hack, the language I work on now, do the same; Hack lambdas capture by value by default. As with any design decision, there are many trade-offs to consider. In this particular case the key tradeoff would be between giving developers flexibility to exactly control the semantics vs doing what you think they mean by default. The former requires more developer education, the latter risks guessing wrong. It's a tough one.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: One of the key reasons why I prefer capturing the variables, not the values, is that it is easy to force a variable to be captured by value: copy it to a fresh variable that does not mutate, close over that. But to simulate capturing a local variable when you capture by value by default you need to do something crazy, like actually capture a single-element array and mutate that element. (Though I note that neither of these would give exactly the semantics of value capture in Hack!)

Comment: @eric well, if by value was default and I need to capture by reference then I'd write (or framework may provide)  a `CaptureByRef<T>` class to hide that craziness but I understand the point. Oh no, now you made me curious about Hack...is it a language we may consider for LOB production code?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Hack is to PHP as TypeScript or Flow is to JavaScript; it is intended to enable developer teams who have large PHP assets to add type discipline gradually.

Comment: VM, JIT compiler, ML...many things now make sense! I'm not PHP programmer but at first sight syntax is interesting, it may even attract NEW programmers without any previous PHP experience. Good luck, I'm sure you will help to make it a good mainstream language!

Comment: Just to make sur I understand, the way I did it is ok?

Comment: Pier, yes the way you write in C# is correct. You should/may mark `str` as `readonly` or `const` (it depends where it's declared) but it's for clarity and/or to prevent mistakes, it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't fully understand how to do it, but the point being I need to declare str as final to acces it in my thread so there is no
>   varaible corruption.

No, the point is that the thread declaration contains a Java closure and this is how Java closures work, i.e. they can only be created using immutable (`final`) objects. The problem does not exist in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `final` in C# is the keyword [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) if it is being used on a field like you are doing or [`sealed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) if it is being used on a class or method.

One note is not strictly required for you to use `readonly` for a variable to be used inside another thread, your code will work as-is right now, but it does ensure you don't accidentally make mistakes that could cause inconsistent behavior because you changed the value of `str` on some other thread.